# Higher Number Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had this 138 tickets of an "event" and the total circulating tickets are 350000. Number of winners are 5000 tickets

What are the chance or probability that 1 of my tickets win?

Tried this on Binomial Calculator web with different tickets (138, 250, etc) but the probabilites goes lower when number of tickets increase, or am I using the wrong method

I'm an engineer but I don't know if this is a silly math question since I don't really get around this kind of problem

Comment: The probability that you win can be found by subtracting the probability that none of the tickets you hold is a winning ticket from $1$.  Do you know how to calculate the number of ways to select $138$ of the $350,000$ tickets? of the $350,000 - 5,000 = 345,000$ tickets which are not winning tickets?

Comment: Is the same ticket allowed to win more than once?

Comment: And are you looking for probability that *exactly* one ticket wins, or that *at least* one ticket wins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the probability that at least one ticket wins, you should go for the probability that no ticket wins.

We can calculate this exactly. The first ticket wins with prob of $p_1 = 5000/350000$. So it looses with $1-p_1$. In this case we have a probability of $5000/349999$ for $p_2$, and so forth. Then we get a total probability of $(1-5000/350000)(1-5000/349999)(1-5000/349998)\ldots(1-5000/349863)$.

But since $138$ is much smaller than $5000$ and $350000$ we can approximate this by assuming replacement, turning this into $(1-5000/350000)^{138}\approx 0.137$, so the prob of at least one winning is about $0.863$.

If we want the prob of exactly one ticket winning, we can also calculate this directly, but it is still sensible to approximate this with replacement. This then gives us a binomial distribution. Then the probabilty of exactly one ticket winning would be
$$ 138 (5000/350000)(1-5000/350000)^{137} \approx 0.275$$
This chance does in fact eventually go down with raising number of tickets, as with raising tickets the chance of getting more than 1 ticket will increase drastically.

Comment: But what if it's at least 2 or 3 or (x) winning tickets? What is the right formula for it?

Comment: Assuming again that we approximate with a binomial distribution (which is okay if the number of tickets we have is much smaller than the number of tickets total and the number of winning tickets):
P(at least 2 win) = 1 - P(0 or 1 win) = $1 - (138(1-5000/350000)^{138} + 137\cdot 138/2 (5000/350000)^1(1-5000/350000)^{137})$

Comment: For the prob that at least 3 win we also have the subtract the prob that exactly 2 win which is $136\cdot 137\cdot 138/6(5000/350000)^2(1-5000/350000)^{136}$

Comment: It's all clear now, thank you so much for the enlightenment